# ZIP function on Dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

I am struggling with an assignment for a course I have entered.

Create a function which returns a list of countries the number of cases is equal to one:
Hint: you can use the zip() function in Python to iterate over two lists at the same time.

So the prior question was to get the number of countries which had a single case of corona.
There was 7 countries as the output - and the following worked for that.

```
# Add your code below
def single_case_country_count(data):
    item = data['Total Cases']
    count = item.count(1)
    if count == 0:
        print('None found')
    return  count
#      pass
```

I am however struggling with the second portion returning the names of these said 7 countries.

type(latest)  is showing dict

i wrote this code
assuming i will have a dictionary of only cases where it is equal to 1 and
the original list; group them through the zipped function and then finally only show the list of countries.

```
def single_case_countries(data):
    cases = data['Total Cases'] == 1
    names = data['Country']
    zipped = zip(names,cases)
    final = list(zipped)
    return final['Country']
#      pass
```

TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

The clear issue here is that I cannot filter on the dictionary using " cases = data['Total Cases'] == 1" as it returns back a boolean.

Was wondering if there is some advice (especially filtering on a dictionary for a specific value

Comment: `data['Total Cases'] == 1` returns a `pd.Series` of boolean values that are true wherever `Total Cases == 1`. You want to do `data[ data['Total Cases'] == 1 ]` to get a `DataFrame` of the rows you need.

Comment: `df.loc[df['Total Cases'] == 1, 'Country']`. Zipping column defeats the purpose of your dataframe. Simply apply the mask to filter where total cases are 1 and the select the column of interest: country.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this with the following code:

```
def single_case_countries(data):
    countries = []
    
    for country,cases in zip(data["Country"],data["Total Cases"]):
        if cases == 1:
           countries.append(country) 
    
    return  countries
```